# Banner Advertising plugins for WordPress

Tags: plugins

I am on the lookout for plugins that can help me set a number of banner spaces with custom sizes, then be able to rotate banners within these spaces. So I could guarantee 10% of all impressions to an advertiser when there are 10 banners for a particular spot.

Any suggestions for good plugins, I don't mind if they are premium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on Google will return you numerous solutions some of which will meet your requirements and that's the best place to find answers to your question as WPSE focusses more so on problem related questions, generally involving code of some nature.

However, some links to get you started:

- [Ad Management Plug-Ins And Tutorials For Your Website](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/19/ad-management-plugins-and-tutorials-for-managing-ads-on-your-website/)
- [9 Best WordPress Ad Management WordPress Plugins](http://millionclues.com/guest-posts/9-best-wordpress-ad-management-plugins/)

The following Google keyword search for the phrase below is where the above two links were pulled from. You might also try any other number of related keyword search to turn up different results.

- [banner ad manager plugin wordpress](https://www.google.com/search?q=banner+ad+manager+plugin+wordpress&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Don't forget to try the WordPress plugin repository for free plugins of which there are many such as,

- [Adwit Banner Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adwit-banner-manager/)

Also consider looking at the following for more Premium plugins,

- [Code Canyon](http://www.codecanyon.net)

There a numerous plugins that exist for this purpose so you should have no trouble sourcing one that meets your exact needs.

PS. The title of this post should be renamed to something a little less ambiguous, in that **'Advertising Plugins for WordPress'** could also refer to the topic of **'advertising your self-created plugin for WordPress'** be it free or premium based. Something along the lines of **'Banner Advertising Plugin...'** would be more appropriate.

PPS. Typically questions like this would be closed without an answer however hopefully this answer helps you and others who might be looking to ask the same question.

**When you do find a plugin that meets your needs, you should update your question by adding a note and link to the plugin of choice just to provide a little more usefulness the overall thread. Good luck!**

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer, will post back if I find a plugin that meets my needs.